# Can counters in python be compared like this?

Tags: python, collections, comparison, counter, reduce

If you compare two counters like this:

```
counter_a == counter_b
```

You get either True or False. However, if you 
were to compare them using `reduce`/ `operator.eq`,
you get False. Can someone please enlighten me 
about what's going on here?

Here's an example:

```
>>> import collections
>>> import operator
>>> a = ['ab', 'ab', 'ab']
>>> b = ['bc', 'ab', 'something']
>>> counters_a = map(collections.Counter, a)
[Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1})]
>>> counters_b = map(collections.Counter, b)
[Counter({'c': 1, 'b': 1}), Counter({'a': 1, 'b': 1}), Counter({'e': 1, 'g': 1, 'i': 1, 'h': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1})]
>>> counters_a[0] == counters_a[1]
True
>>> counters_b[0] == counters_b[1]
False
>>> reduce(operator.eq, [1, 1, 1])
True
>>> reduce(operator.eq, [1, 1, 2])
False
>>> reduce(operator.eq, counters_b)
**False**
>>> reduce(operator.eq, counters_a)
**False**
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are confused about what `reduce` *does*. Given your input, `reduce` does this:

```
((counters_a[0] == counters_a[1]) == counters_a[2])
```

so it compares a boolean `True` or `False` with another counter. Counters are *never* equal to a boolean value. `reduce` runs the operation on the first two elements, then takes the *result* of that operation and uses it as the input for the next loop, together with the next element of the list.

Because the Python `boolean` type is a subclass of `int`, it happens to work for `1` (`True == 1` is `True` in python). Do the same with all `2` values and it'll fail:

```
>>> reduce(operator.eq, [2, 2, 2])
False
```

If you want to test if all counters are the same, use `all()` instead:

```
>>> all(counters_a[0] == c for c in counters_a[1:])
True
>>> all(counters_b[0] == c for c in counters_b[1:])
False
```

Comment: Nitpick: `reduce` doesn't _always_ do that, that's only what it's effectively doing with the usage in this case.

Comment: @martineau: qualified it: "Given your input". :-)